# Display all CONSTRAINT of table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I would like to have some suggestions on how to display all the CONSTRAINTs of a created table in SQL.

I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT(
    USERNAME      VARCHAR(15)     UNIQUE,
    PASSWORD      VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT    ACCOUNT_UNIQUE  UNIQUE(USERNAME),
    CONSTRAINT    ACCOUNT_PK      PRIMARY KEY(USERNAME,PASSWORD)
```

I would like to discover these constraints because when I do / or RUN command in the SQL command line, I can't display those constraints anymore.

Is there a way to display all the CONSTRAINTs for the table ACCOUNT?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Oracle view contains all constraints together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786156/which-oracle-view-contains-all-constraints-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Oracle:

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE table_name = 'ACCOUNT';
```

---

For mySQL

You can use `DESCRIBE ACCOUNT`to view the table structure, included the constraints, or also `SHOW CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT` to see the creation code, which includes the constraints.

Another way is:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ACCOUNT';
```

---

Comment: Already checked, when i do this on the command line i get that :

SQL> DESCRIBE ACCOUNT;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USERNAME                                  NOT NULL CHAR(15)
 PASSWORD                                  NOT NULL CHAR(15)

but not the constrains.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness and fast answer, but when i run this code i get this error :ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

also im not using any graphic interface but just the SQL Command Line prompt editor.

Comment: @Asynchronousx, oh, that's because I've thougt you are using mySQL...  I've added also the SELECT for oracle now... I hope that this time it works :)